# Django : template dictionary/object cross-referencing

Tags: django, django-templates

In Django, a dot in a template variable theoretically signifies a *lookup*, based on the following order of resolution:

- Dictionary lookup. Example: `foo["bar"]`
- Attribute lookup. Example: `foo.bar`
- Method call. Example: `foo.bar()`
- List-index lookup. Example: `foo[bar]`

from [rendering a context in django 1.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/api/#s-rendering-a-context) (docs.djangoproject.com).

In reality:

**view**:

```
...
class Veggie(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
veggies = {'a': Veggie('carrot'), 'b': Veggie('lettuce')}

basket = ['a', 'c', 'b']

return render_to_response('tpls/veggies.txt', 
        {'veggies': veggies, 'basket': basket},
        mimetype="text/plain")
```

**template**:

```
Veggie by basket order, showing name

{% for veg in basket %}
    {{ veg }}
    {{ veggies.veg.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

**output**:

```
Veggie by basket order, showing name

    a

    c

    b
```

No veggie names in that output.

I think this isn't what Django says it does on the tin. I appreciate that I can, a la [Peter Harkins "Django Template Tag for Dictionary Access"](http://push.cx/2007/django-template-tag-for-dictionary-access), write a tag to solve the issue. That's ugly.

This is a *no fix* for the Django team, as per [Django ticket 12486](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12486) because "The intention is that Django's templates can be read and written by non-programmers, so complex logic should be view code or custom template tags." (Luke Plant)

I'd be grateful for some practical advice on writing legible template code in this situation (I've got a lot of "vegetables" of different sorts to dereference). Is it worth stepping away from Django if we've got template-writers who -- ahem -- know how to do dictionary lookups?

Comment: I know you realise what is going on, but I don't understand why you think that contradicts what it says in the documentation. On the contrary, the docs you quote are quite clear, and nothing in them says it will deference a variable to use it as a dictionary key.

Answer (score 2):

Django's template engine is treating `veg` in your for loop as a string, but you are trying to use it as part of an expression.  While Django's template engine is an obstacle at times, what you are doing just doesn't validate.  What you want to do is get the attribute of `veggies` with the name contained in the object `veg`, and dot notation doesn't work that way either in Python or in Django's templates.  When you say veggies.veg, it is looking for an attribute on veggies named `veg`, not named `a`, `b`, or `c`.  This isn't a flaw of the Django template engine; this is just how Python (and every language I'm aware of) works.

Instead, just suck it up and write a template tag to access an attribute, by name, of an arbitrary object, or perhaps pass the template a basket that doesn't require that kind of logic in the template.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Daniel. Clearly what you say is how it works, but the spec notes that the dot *signifies a lookup* -- so it isn't comparable to Python code. I think your "suck it up" comment sums up the situation.

Comment: The religion of neutered template logic is definitely annoying at times, but 9/10 times there's a way to achieve what you want by putting the logic in the view instead... and in the off chance that's not feasible, you can always create a tag or filter for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Django way to do this is to prepare the data structures for rendering in a view (I think that's one of the reasons why is "view" called "view" in django), e.g.

```
basket = [veggies[veg_id] for veg_id in basket_id_list]
```

and then

```
{% for veg in basket %}
    {{ veg.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

So pass structures you want to render, not the structures you get somewhere. It is not true that django consider template writers dumb people unable to understand the dictionary lookup (or e.g. a bit of python code), django considers variable dictionary lookups (as well as arbitrary python code) too complex for template logic, and there are reasons for that. I personally didn't find your template code snippet very readable, but that's personal preferences.

If you disagree with this ideology or it is limiting for your task then it is easy to use a template filter (there is no way to distinguish between dct[var] and dct['var'] with dot-syntax anyway, and the filter is just a one-liner, there is no gain in having it in django itself) or, if this ideology is really disgusting, switch to a different template engine like jinja2.

Comment: The problem is that not all data structure are linear or self-contained in the way you suggest, or may require inefficient iterations to turn them into self-contained structures. Your comment has helped me to be clearer about this point (to myself at least!) -- thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Django is preventing you from putting a quick hack in a template to solve your problem because it enforces a separation between the template authors and the view authors.  Imagine you sold 10,000 different vegetables and you kept them stored in a database table.  Would you really want to pass a dictionary of all 10,000 veggies into the template to enable what you describe?

If you were building this example with real Models instead of classes and dictionaries you would probably already have what you want:  A "basket" would be an object with a foreign key reference to a "veggie" so that `basket_item.veggie` would refer to a row in the Veggie table (ugh, no pun intended).  You could simply pass in the basket and the veggie items would be populated on demand when referenced from the template.  For efficiency you might eventually use a `.select_related` when fetching the basket items to pre-populate the veggie items in a single SQL query.

Comment: The problem isn't being expressed because of a quick hack. I have a master iterator producing nodes off which several dictionaries of objects are referenced. These data structures are highly optimised in plpgsql functions and run orders of magnitude faster than Django's ORM. I think you are saying "don't code like that to use Django"; I disagree with that approach.